# Tag for electromagnetic field

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, we have tag [emf](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emf) with the following description:

> Questions related to the health effects of the electromagnetic field and its many forms, from radio waves to microwaves and x-ray.

Since this tag is not about electromagnetic fields *per se*, but rather about their effects on biological entities, I propose that the tag be renamed [bioelectromagnetism](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioelectromagnetism) or [bioelectromagnetics](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioelectromagnetics) — where [bioelectromagnetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioelectromagnetics) is an actual academic field rather than that whose interaction with biological cells and tissues is being studied.

Comment: I think the problem with that rename is bioelectromagnetism and bioelectronicmagnetics are words almost no one would think to use, while EMF is a commonly used abbreviation that anyone asking a question along those lines is going to know.

Comment: @CareyGregory Where is it commonly used? In the United States? For me, a non-American trained in electrical engineering, EMF stands for *electromotive force*, not for *electromagnetic field*. I had never encountered EMF as an acronym for electromagnetic field until I started reading content on Medical Sciences SE. Still, this is not Physics SE and what is on-topic here is the effect of electromagnetic fields on biological entities. Hence, tag [tag:bioelectromagnetism] with synonyms [tag:electromagnetic-field] and [tag:emf] to ensure that everyone who tries can find the tag.

Comment: I've seen it used to mean electromagnetic field many times in many places, including peer reviewed journal articles, not just here. Google EMF and I think you'll see it's very commonly used that way. The first hit is at cancer.gov, the second is at nih.gov, and the third at who.int, so it's not just laymen. But I guess I'll go along with creating [tag:bioelectromagnetics] and making it a synonym of [tag:emf].

Comment: @CareyGregory The National Cancer Institute, the NIH and the WHO are not laymen, but they are not the IEEE either. Interestingly, [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1029/94RS01918) uses both terms: bioelectromagnetics and EMF.

Comment: I'm confident we'll find many differences in language usage between the IEEE and NIH, and on this site we should be agreeing with NIH more often than IEEE. This is kind of how every software engineer over the age of 40 feels on a daily basis. Hollywood and the popular press have bastardized and distorted one programing word after another. "Hacker" is the prime example. It doesn't mean to me and didn't originally mean to anyone what it means to 99% of the world today.

Comment: @CareyGregory I am attempting to be chronological, rather than tribal. Electromotive force    was a term [before](https://books.google.com/books?id=h944AAAAMAAJ) X-rays were invented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested changes implemented.